# Spring security: how to turn off /logout for non-logged users?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am building a spring security app. Login and logout are working fine, but I would like to make it impossible for non-logged users to logout which is possible by default (strange...).

I tried to add a custom Controller for /logout (checking if user is authenticated) but nothing seems to be working. Is there a way to do it in spring configuration instead? Below is my code. The controller is not working. The default spring-security /logout view is visible even if user is not authenticated.

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import com.example.demo.security.CustomAccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // This will be your home screen URL
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/assets/css/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
        ;
    }
}

-----------------
@RequestMapping("/logout")
    public String logout() {
        if (!(SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext()
                .getAuthentication()
                .getPrincipal() instanceof MyUserPrincipal)) {
//            System.out.println("Non logged user is trying to logout");
            return "redirect:/";
        } else {
//            System.out.println("Logged user is trying to logout");
            return "redirect:/logout";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the code which isn't working?

Comment: I'm wondering: why do you care that a user that isn't logged in can log out? Logging out when you're already logged out is usually a no-op. And obviously the logout view must be visible to an unauthenticated user: they just logged out.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - thanks for Your interest. In my case, wen a non authenticated user gos to /logout url the app asks if he wants to log out ("Are you sure you want to log out?" + a logout button) which is a default spring security funcionality I think. I don't think that a non authenticated user should see this but found no way to disable that for him...

Comment: You should be handling whether user can access the logout page under the `WebSecurityConfig configure` method.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the solution. It appears that the "Are You sure..." page that is showed after a user goes to /logout is generated by CSRF module. After turning of CSRF the page did not show again. That was not the solution though because csrf needs to be enabled for security. One line was missing:
.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
. Now user is logged out after going to /logout with no questions asked. It is not my desired solution but it does the trick for now ;). Thank You all for your responses.

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import com.example.demo.security.CustomAccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // This will be your home screen URL
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/assets/css/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to handle the permissions for the logout URL via the `WebSecurityConfig` class in the `configure` method which you are already doing for some URLs so change to something like:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // This will be your home screen URL
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/assets/css/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccessful")
                .permitAll()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
    ;
}
```

notice the addition of

```
.logout()
.logoutUrl("/logout")
.logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccessful")
.permitAll()
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

This is our logout handling code, so if users hit `/logout` they will be logged out and forwarded to the `/logoutSuccessful` (I would usually redirect to `login` page here).

You can also add a selection of other methods here for configuring your logout as well. The logout is just as configurable as the login, so you can add logout handlers as you see fit.

[image]

Comment: Thank You @Popeye. It did not work for me though. "Are You sure...?" prompt page is still visible even for logged out users. My App uses database user authorisation and CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler. Maybe that is the cause. Still searching...

Comment: You will need to add a custom Logout Handler to check if a logged in user beforehand I believe. It would be difficult to say at this point how that would look, so I would recommend having a look online for a tutorial